# Regular expression equivalent to chomp

Tags: regex, perl

i have seen somewhere instead of using chomp in perl we can use some regular expression to achieve the same task. Can anyone tell what is the regular expression will meet chomp in perl

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give example of your case ?

Comment: You really shouldn't use a regular expression if there's a simple alternative

Comment: @Lorkenpeist TIMTOWTDI, If you want to search them :)

Comment: The "simple alternative" (`chomp`) fails for the case of processing files created on a system with different line endings than those used by the system where it's being processed. (e.g., Processing Windows text files on a *nix box or vice-versa)

Answer (score 11):

What `chomp` does is remove the value of `$/` from the end of its argument string (or `$_` if no argument). So the equivalent regex would be:

```
s#\Q$/\E\z##;
```

Note the use of other delimiter for `s///` to avoid problems with the `$/` variable.

However, there is no benefit to using such a regex, rather the opposite. This is a purely academic question, in my opinion.

Comment: no, `s#\Q$/\z##` (pedantically, with `defined $/ && ! ref $/`, plus a special case for `$/ eq ''`)

Comment: hi, Actually chomp removes the \n at the end of the line.. it's ok if you have a file created in linux environment. consider you have created file in windows environment so end of the line it will have \r\n for new line.. if you use chomp it will remove only \n not \r.. so  "=~ s/\n$//;" regular expression will be  better i guess

Comment: @user2163744 Read about `$/` on this page -> http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html.  This is a more robust solution.

Comment: @user2163744 None of that is true. No, `chomp` removes `$/` from the end of the string, just like I said in my answer. Yes, I am aware of eol problems with files coming from Windows, but that's not a reason to not use `chomp`. No, `s/\n$//` will not fix eol problems since it will not remove `\r`.

Comment: I think, that chomp more simpler.. Will Improve my Perl-Magic skill

Answer (score 6):

At least 995 times out 1000 (with the notable exception of tab-separated data) you want

```
s/\s+\z//;
```

instead of

```
chomp;
```

It handles trailing whitespace (which shouldn't ever be significant), Windows line endings and unix line endings.

Comment: Trailing whitespace is legitimately significant if, say, the data is tab-separated and has trailing empty fields. This method will remove those fields as well as any record separator characters. Generally `s/[\r\n]+\z//` is safer.

Comment: @Borodin, That's like suggesting to remove the wheels from a car to make it safer. There might be some perfectly acceptable uses for cars without wheels, but the rest of the time, you leave them on. `s/[\r\n]+\z//` is dumb, not safer. Use it when you deal with TSV, but not the rest of the time.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Not at all. An empty field should be represented as an empty string; a non-existent field should produce `undef`. What would you expect from data like `3\t\t5`? Should there really be something special about trailing empty fields?

Comment: @SinanÜnür, Some TSV readers care between "missing field" (which would naturally result in undef) and "empty field" (which would naturally result in an empty string).

Comment: @ikegami: You will have to explain your metaphor. What wheels am I removing? I suggest that what you mean is that trailing whitespace should be removed if it insignificant and not otherwise. I have no problem with that. What I do have a problem is your statement that *“trailing whitespace ... should never be significant”* which is nonsense.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: So you are saying that there is no way to represent an empty string with tab-separated data? Then you are at odds with popular usage and the MIME standard.

Comment: @Borodin, It *should* never be significant. It *is* in the case of TSV, and that's unfortunate. I never said should never use `chomp`. I said `s/\s+\z//g` should be used instead more than 995 times in every 1000.

Comment: @ikegami: I doubt if you meant to make a comment on the usefulness of data formats with significant trailing whitespace. If you did then you should rewrite your answer, as it implies that stripping all trailing whitespace is probably fine. Tab-separated data is far from uncommon.

Comment: @SinanÜnür: No one has mentioned anything beyond pure mechanics. Even if we were considering the next level of information then what better way to represent an empty string than with an empty string? Saying that an empty string in the record means missing data and there must be some special encoding to represent an empty string seems perverse. Yes, there are several representations for the absence of data - Perl's `undef` and SQL's `NULL` are amongst the most obvious - but everywhere I can think of a null string is a null string. Making trailing tabs insignificant in TSV is a loss of data.

Comment: @Borodin It may seem perverse, but in practice, it is valuable to know the difference between not having a value in a field due to a predefined reason versus not knowing why there isn't one is important. In any case, I am not sure if this is the place for this argument, so I am cleaning up the comments.

Comment: @Borodin, Don't change >99.5% to >=50%! That's not the same message at all!

Comment: @ikegami: What you have written is poor and the hyperbole is misleading. How about this version?

Comment: @Borodin, 1) If what I had was hyperbole, so is your replacement. They both use the same figure. 2) I actually understated the number of times `chomp` would be better. That's the opposite of hyperbole.

Comment: @ikegami: What you have written is an opinion, yet you present it as a truism. It also reads as a recommendation to always strip all trailing whitespace, when I think you meant to comment on the validity of formats where such whitespace *is* significant. At least you have condescended to include an explicit mention of tab-separated data. You are being petty now and I will leave you to your arrogance.

Comment: @Borodin, Every post is an opinion, but it IS a truism that significant trailing whitespace causes nothing but trouble. Stop acting like a baby and recognize when you're wrong. Your slew of bad edits is the hallmark of a 5 year old! You've got to stop spamming with unbacked contradictions.